# Adding A String Literal To SQL Results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query similar to the below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) TheseMatch, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [MyTable]) ThisIsMyTotal
FROM [MyTable]  
WHERE MyCondition = 'MyCondition'
```

I am trying to add a string literal to this, that will be available on the same returned row. I have been trying this:

```
SELECT 'THIS IS MY STRING' as Note,
SELECT COUNT(*) TheseMatch, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [MyTable]) ThisIsMyTotal
FROM [MyTable]  
WHERE MyCondition = 'MyCondition'
```

However this returns a syntax error. What would be the proper way to explicitly specify a string literal, and add it to the results?

TIA!

Comment: It's unclear from your query what you're trying to do, perhaps a very small sample of your data and your desired output would help.

Comment: What is the syntax error, and what do you want to add the string literal to?  Do you want the data in the returned column to look like "Number of matches: 10"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right syntax would be something like

```
SELECT 'THIS IS MY STRING' as Note,
     COUNT(*) TheseMatch, 
     (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [MyTable]) ThisIsMyTotal
FROM [MyTable]  
WHERE MyCondition = 'MyCondition'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'THIS IS MY STRING' as Note,   
SELECT COUNT(*) TheseMatch, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Banks) ThisIsMyTotal
FROM Banks  
WHERE Banks.Name = 'MyCondition'
```